# How do I get my GitLab project to auto-update on Packagist.org?

Tags: composer-php, gitlab, packagist

I have posted my libre software GitLab project on Packagist, and this succeeded but Packagist indicates next to its name that it "Does not auto-update".  It does not say how to make it so it automatically updates.

Answer (score 2):

GitLab [added](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/14493) official [integration with Packagist](https://packagist.org/about#how-to-update-packages) so you just need to go to Integrations and enable it (or go directly to gitlab.com/[your-org]/[your-project]/services/packagist/edit) and enter your username and API token from your [Packagist profile](https://packagist.org/profile/) and everything is all set.